# Ionic 4 - click event not working on browserstack but working on browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, browserstack

I thought the issue was with (click), as click is been used in the browser (working) but in mobile it is a touch not click (not working). So I have tried up with on-touch, (ontouchend) instead of (click) but nothing is working.

Later I feel that problem is with this below code snippet.

```
var event: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement;
event.click();`
```

This is my code

.html

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label class="amount-label pr1">Other</ion-label>
    <ion-radio id="other" class="mr2" mode="md" slot="start" value="other" (click)="toggleAmount('O')">
    </ion-radio>
    <div class="mt3 other-dollar">
        <ion-input currencyTypo class="other-amount-section" placeholder="0.00" (input)="validateAmount($event.target.value)" maxLength="7" type="number" pattern="^\d* (\.\d{0,2})?$" (click)="checkRadio('other')" formControlName = "otherAmount">
         <div class="dib pr1">$</div>
         </ion-input>
     </div>
</ion-item>
```

.ts

```
checkRadio(id: string) {
    var event: HTMLElement = document.getElementById(id) as HTMLElement;
    event.click();
}
```

I expect the radio button should checked as soon as i clicked on the ion-text field.

Answer (score 0):

As you encounter this only when testing on mobile devices the issue might be related to Ionic v4. You could review the following issues reported around the same behavior here - [#1](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-radio-button-is-checked-but-display-not-checked/162594/7), [#2](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11419), [#3](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14057#issuecomment-319415663)